# Zip file not downloading c# from url with webclient

Tags: c#, download, webclient

So I have a form which downloads stock images for the OnePlus One and its not even attempting to download the file from the link (direct) http://builds.cyngn.com/factory/bacon/cm-11.0-XNPH05Q-bacon-signed-fastboot.zip

It just jumps to the complete method and its not catching the exception. The code for the download part is below (if you need more I can provide as it checks the percentage and grabs the file size from the server as well). Whereas it should download the file to the path specified...

```
InitializeComponent();
        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
        sw.Start();
        try
        {
            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://builds.cyngn.com/factory/bacon/cm-11.0-XNPH05Q-bacon-signed-fastboot.zip"), @"\resources\stock.zip");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

I think its todo with the fact its running `webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);` when its obviously not complete.

Comment: What do you mean by `It just jumps to complete and its not catching the exception`. I guess it starts the async download and you never wait till `Completed` method is called

Comment: it calls the Completed method rather than the download then the Completed method...

Comment: And you think it is not important to post what is returned in *Error* property in the `Completed` method ? (BTW: Can you fix your previous comment so that I can understand it correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It was due to unhandled exceptions within the code. ( I will post it later as this is from mobile) so now its forced to run by checking an if statement that returns false and then runs.